# Absolute value of an integer

Tags: r, if-statement

So I am trying to find an absolute value of an x integer using if statement and not abs() in r.
Can you help me please?

Comment: `x <- -5:5; if (TRUE) x * sign(x)`

Comment: It says in if(x<0) { the condition has length >1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: I suspect that the downvoting is an implicit criticism of seeING obvious homework posted without any background or statements about your academic institution‘s policy on that matter. To make a better question you might post first a test case, a more complete description of inputs and then show what attempts have been made.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
> v <- -3:3
> v
[1] -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3
> ifelse(v<0,-v,v)
[1] 3 2 1 0 1 2 3
>
```

As you can see this is a vectorized if-else.

Comment: Yes but I want to know how I can run it from r-script and gives no error in the console

Comment: Just typing it in a script?

Comment: Sort of a r-code in if statement

Comment: Yes. Just create a function or script. You can put anything you want in them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following logic in the programming language of your choice

```
if i < 0, then i = -i
else i
```

Edit: Suggested by a user in the comments.

Comment: Usually we write `i-2*i` as `-i`.